# PL/SQL: procedure with table and column name as parameters

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, parameter-passing, procedure, tablename

I would like to write a procedure in PL\SQL, which would change the special characters (in the example below: a hash) to a apriori declared characters (in the example below: an underscore). The procedure should take a table name and a column name as parameters. I wrote such a code, however, it doesn't work:

```
create or replace procedure change_chars(table_name in varchar2, column_name in varchar2)
    begin
        execute immediate 'update ' || table_name ||
        ' set ' || column_name || ' = replace(' || column_name ||', '''#''', '''_''')';
    end;
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: "it doesn't work" ... http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#bespecific ... that said, you have too many single-quotes which means that `#` and `_` are being interpreted as code rather than as part of the string to execute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the `IS` just before the `BEGIN` and you have too many quotes in your string:

```
create or replace procedure change_chars(table_name in varchar2, column_name in varchar2) is
begin
    execute immediate 'update ' || table_name ||
    ' set ' || column_name || ' = replace(' || column_name ||', ''#'', ''_'')';
end;
```

To handle strings with quotes, you could use the [`Q` operator](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00218) instead:

```
' set ' || column_name || ' = replace(' || column_name || q'[, '#', '_')]';
```